# Ошибка при парсинге данных с помощью Selenium в Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

я хочу спарсить некоторые данные на сайте с помощью `Selenium`. Но получаю пустую строку

Код страницы можете посмотреть на сайте: https://www.roblox.com/users/1157561093/profile

Вот код:

```
driver.get(link)
    sleep(20)
    disp_name = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="container-main"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1[1]').text
    name = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="container-main"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]').text
    join_date = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="profile-statistics-container"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/p[2]').text
    data = (disp_name, name, join_date)
    return dict(zip(('Display name', 'Username', 'Join date'), data))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все данные кроме `join_date` нашлись а вот при его парсинге получаю пустую строку.
Что делать?

Comment: Скроллить в конец страницы и парсить все что вам нужно

Comment: а без скролла не работает что-ли??!

Comment: Даже со скроллом не работает, как не пытался не могу получить дату

Comment: со скроллом у меня все сработало, огромное спасибо! использовал эту строчку кода: driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")